# Golang calling a function without implementation

Tags: go

I'm very new to Golang and I recently stumbled across this neat package for testing called "testify". And in it, I noticed that all you have to do is add an additional *mock* object to our testing struct:

```
type MyTestObject struct {
     // add a Mock object instance
     mock.Mock
     // other fields go here as normal
}
```

And out of nowhere, we're allowed to call a function named *called*

```
func (o *MyTestObject) SavePersonDetails(firstname, lastname string, age int) (int, error) {
  args := o.Called(firstname, lastname, age)
  return args.Int(0), args.Error(1)
}
```

As a new Golang programmer, this completely throws me off. How does this work? How, by just adding another field in the struct, are we allowed to call a function that we did not implement? Did I miss an important lesson in Golang here? Is this a thing I can do in my programs too? If so, can someone point me at a tutorial/description of how to do this?

Comment: This is [struct embedding](https://gobyexample.com/struct-embedding) in Go, which allows for composition of types. So the `Called` function is defined on the `mock.Mock` type and is available on `MyTestObject` through composition.

Comment: And: you'll find the definition of `Called` in the documentation for the `Mock` type, [here](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/stretchr/testify/mock#Mock.Called).

Comment: Note that the language is called Go.